# Space of continuous functions $f: [a,b] \to G$ where $G \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following claim in my lecture notes on ODEs.

> Theorem:
>
> Let $f: [a,b] \to G$ where $G \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is closed and
> define
>
> $\| f \|_{\infty}=sup_{t}\lvert f(t) \rvert=max_{t}\lvert f(t) \rvert$
> where $\vert f(t) \rvert$ denotes a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.
>
> Then $C([a, b],G)$ with norm $\| f \|_{\infty}$ is a Banach space.

The author notes that it's not necessary to specify which norm we mean since all norms on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ are equivalent.

I've first looked at a proof of the theorem for $d=1$. A proof can be found [here](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/%7Efjmliou/Complex/spbounded.pdf).

The idea is to show that the space of all real-valued bounded functions on $X$, call it $B(X)$, is complete and if $X$ is compact, then the space of continuous functions on $X$ is a closed subset of $B(X)$.

I think this proof can be generalized to real vector-valued functions. So consider the space of bounded real vector-valued functions $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and define

$\| f \|_{\infty,vector}=\sup \limits_{t}\| f(t) \|_{2}$ where $\| f(t) \|_{2}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Proof:
Let $f_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $n,m \geq N \implies \| f_{n} - f_{m} \|_{\infty,vector}<\epsilon$. Hence for all $x \in X$, $\| f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x) \|_{2} \leq \| f_{n} - f_{m} \|_{\infty,vector}<\epsilon$.

This implies that for each $x \in X$, the sequence of real vectors $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is complete, $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is convergent. Let the limit of $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ be $f(x)$, i.e. f(x) =
$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$. Hence, we obtain a function $f(x)$ on $X$. On the other hand, a Cauchy sequence in a normed space must be bounded, i.e. there exists $M>0$ so that $\| f_{n} \|_{\infty,vector} \leq M$. In other words, for each $x \in X$, $\| f_{n}(x) \|_{2} \leq \| f_{n} \|_{\infty,vector} \leq M$. Taking $n \to \infty$, we find $\| f(x) \|_{2} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \| f_{n}(x) \|_{2} \leq M$, for each $x \in X$ by the continuity of the norm. This shows that $f(x)$ is a bounded function on $X$ and thus $f \in B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Furthermore, for each $x \in X$, and $n \geq N$, $\| f_{n}(x) - f(x) \|_{2} = \lim \limits_{m \to \infty}\| f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x) \|_{2} \leq \epsilon$.

This shows that for $n \geq N$, $\| f_{n} - f \|_{\infty,vector} \leq \epsilon$. We find $f$ is the limit of $\{f_{n}\}$ in $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$: This proves that $\{f_{n}\}$ is convergent in $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$.

We can also again show that the space of continuous functions on $X$, call it $C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$, is a closed subset of $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$.

Proof:
Let f be a limit point of $C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$, then f is a bounded real vector-valued function. There exists $\{f_{n}\}$ in $C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$ so that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to f in $B(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$. To show $f \in C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$, we need to show that f is a continuous function.

Given $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $N>0$ so that $\| f_{N} - f \|_{\infty,vector}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Since $f_{N}$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$, so that if $d(x,y)<\delta$, $\| f_{N}(x) - f_{N}(y) \|_{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ where $d$ is a metric on $X$. If $d(x,y)<\delta$, we see

$\| f(x) - f(y) \|_{2} \leq \| f(x) - f_{N}(x) \|_{2} + \| f_{N}(x) - f_{N}(y) \|_{2} + \| f_{N}(y) - f(y) \|_{2}$

$\leq 2 \| f - f_{N} \|_{\infty,vector} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} < \epsilon$.

This shows that f is uniformly continuous on X and hence continuous.

Now I've got two questions.

1. Why does it not matter which norm we use on $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ to define the supremum norm in the vector-valued case? I think the definition makes sense since we know that all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R^{d}}$, so that the boundedness of the range w.r.t the Euclidean norm can be used to bound the range with any other norm. The crucial step in the proof was that $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ is complete with the Euclidean norm such that the pointwise limit exists. Is $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ with other norms also complete simply by the equivalence of norms?
2. How can I show the same results for functions with range $G \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ where $G$ is closed? I think the proof in general works fine since a closed subset of a complete space is also complete, but I don't see how I can show that the subset of functions with range $G$ is a vector subspace of $C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$. How do we know that the space is closed by addition and scalar multiplication?

Edit:

To be more precise regarding 2): How can we show that the set of continuous functions $f: [a,b] \to G$ where $G \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ is closed is a vector space. I think it should be a subspace of $C(X,\mathbb{R}^{d})$. But how can we show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Thanks very much for any help and suggestions!

Comment: it seems the statement of the theorem is incomplete?

Comment: Whoops, I must've accidently deleted a line. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Yes for 1) because if a sequence is Cauchy the it is Cauchy in any equivalent norm. 2) $G$ is complete because it is a closed subspace of a Banach space.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. 1) I guess this is exactly what I meant. If a sequence is Cauchy with some norm, then it is Cauchy with any other norm in $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ since all norms are equivalent. But then any Cauchy sequence convergences with the Euclidean norm which again can be used to show that it converges with any other norm as well. 2) I know that G is complete cause it is a closed subset of a complete space, but I want to show that $C(X,G)$ is complete. But how do I know that this is even a vector space? Maybe I'm missing something.